# Execute program when device is connected

Tags: c#

I have been tasked to make a program that takes a screenshot of our cameras (and other things) that are attached to our cars, every 10 minutes.
I have essentially made the program, but they want the program to only execute, once the camera is attached.
The camera is being connected to a computer via. ethernet and have a static ip address of 172.31.44.1.
I've been thinking about pinging the camera and then run everything afterwards.
The thing is, if the camera is being disconnected, then I want the program to not exit, but just stop and then go again, if the camera is being connected again.

The code that's being run is this:

```
do
{
    WindowState.GetWindowState();
    _captureScreen();
    Console.WriteLine($"Screenshot was taken at {DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay}");
    Thread.Sleep(10 * 60 * 1000);
    
} while (true);
```

What would be the best solution?
An event that's being triggered? A ping of the camera? Perhaps a Windows Event?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Rather than sleeping for 10 minutes within the application, why not let the OS schedule the program to run every 10 minutes?

Comment: I could do that, but that doesn't really solve what I am asking.
I need to have the program running when the camera is connected and stopping again when it's disconnected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not try catching the exception that is thrown when camera is disconnecting?

```
do
{
    try
    {
        WindowState.GetWindowState();
        _captureScreen();
        Console.WriteLine($"Screenshot was taken at {DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay}");
        Thread.Sleep(10 * 60 * 1000);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Could not connect at {DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay}");
    }    
} while (true);
```

Just make sure you replace `catch(Exception ex)` with the specific exception that is thrown when you can't connect to the camera.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!
Will there be an exception to catch, if it's over ethernet rather than a USB?

Comment: Why don't you run and see if you get an exception. Alternatively do you have a return value you can inspect?